# Why doesn't my string change?

Tags: java

```
public static void read(String a[], double b[], String c) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        int i = 0;
        String id = in.next();
        String name = in.next();
        String lastname = in.next();
        double grade = in.nextDouble();
        if (name.substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase(c)) {
            a[i] = id + "\t" + name + "\t" + lastname + "\t" + grade;
            b[i] = grade;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

When I use this method with

```
String men[] = new String[501];
double menGrade[] = new double[501];
read(men, menGrade, "MR");
```

My men[0] is assigned a String but men[1] to men [500] are all null ...

Comment: You mean men[1] to men [500] are all null

Comment: is you if statement executed more then once?

Comment: what is the content of the `data.txt` file? note your `while` will be running as long as the `in.hasNext()` is true

Comment: Can you add System.out.println("test") bellow your if statement and system.out.println("test2") as first line bellow you while loop and tell us the results.

Comment: It might also be worth adding say, the first 10 lines of the text file to check that it passes the substring test consistently

Comment: Attach a debugger, stick in a breakpoint and see how many times the loop is executed and if the executions pass the `if`.

Comment: test2
test
test2
test2
test
test2
test2
test
test2
test2
test
test2



This is a result for @Thijser

Comment: Have you considered using Lists instead of arrays? You don't know how many MR you will find in the file.

Comment: plz. don't delete question its helps others.

Comment: @user3073687 You aren't supposed to throw away your question text. The point is to keep questions and answers around.

Comment: Pls don't delete the original post, you are wasting others' effort . People around here spend nice amount of time to read your question and provide best as of their knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
  int i = 0;
  ...
```

This will RESET i each time you start the while loop and you always overwrite a[0] and b[0].

swap these two lines! (so the int i = 0; comes before the loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (in.hasNext()) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to declare your variable `i` outside of the while loop to keep it incremented.

Right now you are

- declaring it with value 0
- assign the values to the 1st array position
- increment i, and then
- declare it again with value 0 at the next loop iteration.

SO, just change your lines:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    int i = 0;
```

to

```
int i = 0;
while (in.hasNext()) {
```

Your code has also other issues which you should adress in some way.
I do not know why you initialize your array with a fixed size of 500 and also check some conditions before you add your men and grades to those Arrays. This will however lead to a few problems if you are not careful.

Right now you would have holes in your array whenever the if condition does not evaluate to true.

Also your program would crash if there is more than 500 entries in your file.

A rather good solution when dealing with dynamic data structures (so, when you do not know beforehand how many records you will have exactly), is to use a dynamic data structure.

In java you can have a look at `java.util.List` interface and probably `java.util.ArrayList` as a good implementation.
Here is also the java doc of that class: [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Here you find more on the collections api which are a good thing for dynamic data structures: [Collections - List tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html)

Comment: damn, faster than me :P

Comment: Did not try to be fast :) Commented on another answer before which then got deleted which made me putting up this answer.

Comment: ^^ Well, I was slow :P

Comment: Good catch Matthias :P

Answer (score 1):

You should increment `i` in your if statement and not always like you do now. You don't want holes in your men array.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means, either your loop is executing only once.
Or, if block in loop is exceuting only once.

Dependecy is on the content of file you are importing and your if condition.

Comment: At the moment, this answer isn't much more than speculation, without the appropriate evidence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that something is wrong with your "data.txt" that caused the while loop to execute only once. Otherwise, I don't see any mistake in the code.

Why don't you check the value of i during the execution of the program?

Comment: At the moment, this answer isn't much more than speculation, without the appropriate evidence.

Comment: Yes - I failed to notice the error in declaring i inside the while loop :(

Answer (score 0):

If your `data.txt` file contains `One` single line then the corresponding `while` will be running for once populating the first element of the array i.e `men` in your case

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    int i = 0;
    ...
    i++;
}
```

you are destroying and creating `i` variable each time loop is executed effectively reseting it to 0 each time. Asides from notes from other answers you can simply move `i` outside the loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (in.hasNext()) {
    ...
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Now I can't run in myself*, but I see

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
        int i = 0;
//other
  a[i] = id + "\t" + name + "\t" + lastname + "\t" + grade;
            b[i] = grade;
        }
        i++;
```

If you use  a **counter** *i* over an array/Collection, generally you have to give a greater scope to counter.
if the **counter** is inside the while, at every iteration you recreate the **counter** and you point always at the same element of array

The/one solution can be:

```
int i=0;
while (in.hasNext()) {
//etc
```

Comment: Yeah I just realize that 1 min ago thk lot